# Readings for 安 as しずか (Surname)

Tags: readings, names, multiple-readings

Is it possible to read 安 as しずか *shizuka*? Kanshudo.com has this pronunciation as an additional reading for a surname:

https://www.kanshudo.com/name/%E5%AE%89

I wanted to do some research before asking you all this question, so I already checked on Jisho.org and Wiktionary where the only readings that were mentioned were:

> Kun: やす.い、 やす.まる、 やす、 やす.らか 
> On: アン
>
> Go-on: あん (an, Jōyō)
> Kan-on: あん (an, Jōyō)
> Kun: やすい (yasui, 安い, Jōyō); やすらか (yasuraka, 安らか); やすんじる (yasunjiru, 安んじる); いずくんぞ (izukunzo, 安んぞ)
> Nanori: あ (a); あす (asu); あず (azu); あっ (a'); や (ya)

What adds to my confusion is that 静か ('quiet') seems to be the normal way to write しずか.

I'm taking an uneducated guess that this reading for 安 must be uncommon, because neither Jisho.org nor Wiktionary have しずか as a possible reading.  So is it possible to read 安 as しずか for a surname, even though 静か is the normal way of writing the adjective 'quiet'?  Would 安 (しずか) as a surname be too strange or weird, or just uncommon?

Answer (score 2):

The characters appearing in the 戸籍 *koseki* (family register) are [publicly accessible](http://houmukyoku.moj.go.jp/KOSEKIMOJIDB/M01.html). As far as I can tell, one cannot search how common a name is, or in what combinations they appear. But from this data we can rule out that 安 is a surname with reading しずか. 安 is listed with the following readings:

<kbd>音読み **アン**
訓読み **やすい**、**いずくに**、
**いずくにか**、**いずくんぞ**、**やすんじる**
[image: 安]
6画</kbd>

On the other hand, some of the *kanji* appearing in the *koseki* with reading しずか (in total 11, including 静) are the following:

<kbd>音読み **ジャク**、**セキ**
訓読み **さび**、**さびしい**、**さびれる**、
**しずか**
[image: しずか]
11画</kbd>
<kbd>音読み **セン**、**ゼン**
訓読み **ゆずる**、**しずか**

[image: しずか]
15画</kbd>
<kbd>音読み **タン**
訓読み **しずか**

[image: しずか]
16画</kbd>
<kbd>音読み **ヒツ**、**ビツ**、**ミチ**
訓読み **しずか**

[image: しずか]
17画</kbd>
<kbd>音読み **セイ**、**ジョウ**
訓読み **しずか**

[image: しずか]
16画</kbd>
<kbd>音読み **ゲキ**
訓読み **しずか**

[image: しずか]
18画</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  I have two clarification questions. 
 Which of these four readings (いずくに, いずくにか, いずくんぞ, or やすんじる) is best for a surname?  And secondly, when you write out the surname, do you simply write the kanji 安, or do you have to add the 送り仮名 after it?  For example, 安くに, 安くにか, 安くんぞ, or 安んじる?

Comment: https://namegen.jp/yomikata?name=%E5%AE%89 seems to point that only two readings of 安 as a surname are aven moderately popular: あん and やす. Out of these, あん seems to be filled at least by Korean and Chinese migrants having this surname.

On the other hand, https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=%E5%AE%89 has readings やす,やすい,やすき,やすし,やすこ,あん,あなし,はだかす,しずか, all of which seemingly occur at the moment. It has more statistics, such as there are around 4'000 people around Japan with a surname spelt like that. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a joint statistic, with spelling and readings.